computer freezes while installing Ubuntu LTS 24.05
It freezes at step 4 portioning:   does not read existing hard drive, nor allow any input.  The screen freezes.  And is totally unresponsive.
Including the quit, back and install Now boxes.
Bad or incomplete download?    USB drive of 64Gb with no data, other than Rufus on it.  And the .iso file for installation

Presumably you mean 24.04 lts?

Did you hashcheck check the downloaded iso?   See   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToSHA256SUM
Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
http://releases.ubuntu.com under the SHA256SUMS link.

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ will yes 24.04 LTS. oops
